# Grails dependencies 'empty' in java build path STS

Tags: eclipse, grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

My coworker is attempting to install STS, groovy/grails onto his PC.  He has imported a TFS project which grabbed the source fine.  However he is getting lots of build errors that appear to be the result of the Grails Dependencies library being empty.  He cleared .ivy2 cache and restarted STS which repopulated the .ivy2 cache.  However, the dependencies are still empty under the build path (right click project, build path, libraries tab, expand Grails Dependencies).

He might be able to add them manually, but that doesn't seem like the appropriate solution and may cause issues down the line.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select "Grails Tools -> Refresh dependencies" from the context menu of your project. Then the dependencies are added.

Comment: I'll tell him to give that a try.

Comment: Well, he doesn't seem to have a '$WorkspaceName'\.metadata\.plugins\com.springsource.sts.grails.core '$ProjectName'-dependencies.xml file.  So even when refreshing its not going to pick up anything.

Comment: He is also missing the folder for C:\Documents and Settings\$USER_ID\.grails\1.3.7\projects\$PROJECT_NAME\plugins  which means that tomcat and hibernate aren't available.

Comment: Well theoretically he will build it up. Is the project compiling? Sometimes you need do a `grails compile` or even do the `refresh dependencies` twice.

Comment: When it compiles it comes back with 800+ errors.  He's attempted to completely clean his computer of TFS workspaces, STS install, Groovy install, Grails install, but something is still corrupt.  Not even sure what to try at this point.

Comment: When refreshing it goes out and downloads the dependencies, but never appears to get around to setting them under the library section of build path.  Not sure where the disconnect is.

Comment: Are there some dependencies to other projects, which are also not compiling? This can happen, when `grails compile` fails. Refresh dependencies will add dependencies to classpath, when it can succeed. Try make `grails compile` from command line. If this fails, refresh dependencies will fail as well.

Comment: We finally got it to compile.  Not entirely sure of the root cause which is frustrating, but at least with the new install the application.properties needed to be changed for tomcat and hibernate from 1.3.6 to 2.0.1.  There doesn't seem to be a difference between 1.3.6 and 1.3.7, so we more or less ignored that piece for a while.  2.0.1 also complains about a separate issue in our code, but we'll work on reverting to 1.3.6 on his machine later.  Thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It turned out that an undeclared class was causing the problem. One of the STS engineers responded that "if the command "grails compile" fails, then STS will not have the dependency data. This data is produced as a side effect of the compile command. So it doesn't get generated if the compile fails."

Basically, the entire Grails Dependency issue was a red herring. If you look at the Error Log (Window->View->Error Log or Window->View->Other: General->Error Log) check to see there is an undefined that is stopping the grails compile.